# Restful services with Spring Boot on Wildfly 8.x

Tags: java, rest, maven, spring-boot, wildfly-8

I'm having issues getting a simple hello world application to work on Wildfly 8.x.  The stack trace I receive is a null pointer exception getting the headers of the response:

```
2016-07-15 04:14:28,488 ERROR [org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter] (default task-4) Forwarding to error page from request [/hello] due to exception [null]: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.ArrayList.<init>(ArrayList.java:177) [rt.jar:1.8.0_92]
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.getHeaders(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:248) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.getHeaders(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:303) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpResponse$ServletResponseHttpHeaders.get(ServletServerHttpResponse.java:160) [spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpResponse$ServletResponseHttpHeaders.containsKey(ServletServerHttpResponse.java:142) [spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.addContentDispositionHeader(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:346) [spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:238) [spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
```

I threw together the quickest simplest Spring Boot restful service I could imagine:

```
package com.tryme;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class TrymeController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/hello")
    public ResponseEntity<String> hello()
    {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("Hello world.", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

The application main is:

```
package com.tryme;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
public class TrymeApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(TrymeApplication.class, args);

    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(TrymeApplication.class);
    }
}
```

I read several blog posts advising how to change your pom to support restful spring services, and this is the POM I created (I tried with both 3.1 servlet and 2.5).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.tryme</groupId>
    <artifactId>tryme</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>tryme</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <start-class>com.tryme.TrymeApplication</start-class>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--
        <dependency>  
             <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>  
             <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>  
             <version>2.5</version>  
             <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>        
         -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <!--We are building spring boot application with maven-->
    <build>
        <finalName>tryme</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <!--Repositories for spring libs-->
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <!--Repositories for needed plugins -->
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>    
</project>
```

I tried forcing headers on my ResponseEntities, and it did't help.  Can anyone tell me if there's anything I can change to get this simple app up and running with Spring Rest on 8.x Wildfly?  I verified it works fine on 9.x and 10.x

Edit: here is what my latest war looks like.
[image]

Comment: Just a note: you must make the servlet-api dependency provided, or else you're going to deploy it as part of your application and you really do not want that.

Comment: Do you have a valid context for the application i.e. by class like that: `@ApplicationPath("rest")
public class ConfigApp extends Application {
   public ConfigApp(){
   }
}` ?

Comment: The *start-class* is wrong. It should be: `com.tryme.TrymeApplication`rather than `tryme.TrymeApplication`

Comment: The generated *war* contains `tomcat-embed-el.jar`  even you have marked `spring-boot-starter-tomcat.jar` as provided. You have to exclude it explicitly.

Comment: Ok, I have corrected the pom to reflect these suggestions, and I'm getting the same result.  For what it's worth, I get the same result when I use rest services in Spring MVC instead of Spring Boot.  If I deploy the same app on Wildfly 9.x or 10.x, it works.  However, I am trying eventually to deploy my application to JBPM which is sitting on 8.2 or 8.1 depending on the version.

Comment: Hrabosch, I wasn't sure what you meant by ConfigApp so I Googled for it.  I think that pertains only to JaxRS services.  Does that sound correct?  None of the Spring Boot / Spring MVC guides mention anything about ConfigApp, but I think the same purpose is served by the following:    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(TrymeApplication.class);
    }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a bug in Undertow < 1.1.0-Final. Wildfly 8.1 uses Undertow 1.0.15.

In *Untertow 1.0.x* the `getHeaders(String)` method **does not** check the response headers for `null`.

```
// from Undertow 1.0.15-final 
// http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/io.undertow/undertow-servlet/1.0.15.Final/io/undertow/servlet/spec/HttpServletResponseImpl.java#HttpServletResponseImpl.getHeaders%28java.lang.String%29
@Override
public Collection<String> getHeaders(final String name) {
    return new ArrayList<String>(exchange.getResponseHeaders().get(name));
}
```

From *Undertow 1.1.0* upwards the `getHeaders(String)` the methods checks the responseHeaders for `null`

```
// from Undertow 1.1.0-final 
// http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/io.undertow/undertow-servlet/1.1.0.Final/io/undertow/servlet/spec/HttpServletResponseImpl.java#HttpServletResponseImpl.getHeader%28java.lang.String%29
@Override
public Collection<String> getHeaders(final String name) {
   HeaderValues headers = exchange.getResponseHeaders().get(name);
    if(headers == null) {
        return Collections.emptySet();
    }
    return new ArrayList<>(headers);
}
```

Unfortunately I have not found the corresponding bug report  in the JBoss / Undertow issue tool.

So the only way to overcome this is to patch / overwrite the `io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl`

Update the old jars in `modules/system/layers/base/io/undertow/` with new ones

- io.undertow.core
- io.undertow.servlet

You have to modify the `module.xml`in the corresponding directory.

Not sure about

- io.undertow.jsp
- io.undertow.websocket

For your example it's enough to update core and servlet.
Better upgrade to the latest wildly 8.2 release if possible.

See also discussion on the [JBoss forum](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/256553?start=0&tstart=0&_sscc=t)

Comment: Thanks so much!  I knew there had to be a bug.  Excuse the ignorance, but I haven't been on JBoss since 2005.  How would I go about patching undertow?  :)

Comment: Googling, it sounds like you just add the dependencies in your pom, or download the updates and drop them into your server?  That's what I considered doing in the first place, but it seemed a little crazy.  :)

Comment: Yes, that are the ways how to patch it.

Comment: Actually, JBPM 6.4 comes packaged with a version of Wildfly (8.2.1) that works with Spring REST.  However, if you are adding Spring Tool Suite to the version of Eclipse that it is configured to download (MARS), you need to download Spring Tool Suite from the update site itself instead of marketplace:  http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.5/

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution. Saved my day. This is the issue here I guess https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-3474